# trouble with python double iteration

Tags: python-2.7, iteration, nested-loops

Hi and thanks in advance for the help.

I am a beginner in Python and I am having issues with iteration. I understand itertools is probably part of the solution to my problem but I don't seem to formulate it right and I couldn't find a problem similar enough on the forums.

Based on a numpy indices vector V, another vector Y and some function f, I would like to compute something like:

```
for i in V[:-1]:
    for j in V[i+1:]:
        f(Y[i], Y[j])
```

... which as you know doesn't work because you understand python better than I do! It seems never to get to "j" (V not being iterable twice is what I understood so far, although I'm not sure what it means).

What would be a good way to do that? Note that it is quite important not to compute both f(Y[i],Y[j]) and f(Y[j],Y[i]) since it is symmetric and quite long to run.

Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that itertools.combinations seems to work: 

    `from itertools import combinations

    for (element1, element2) in combinations(Y[V], 2):
        f(element1, element2) `

I don't know if it is the best way to go, but at least it solves my problem!

Comment: This is definitely a good way to solve this problem, and this is essentially what `itertools.combinations` is for. You should post this as the answer to your question.